# when testing sqlite3 under python3 script ("755" set) strato throws error "End of script output before headers" - why?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

there are only 2 functions and 1 import.
after running the script, the db has been generated ..
the server responds with 500 error

> Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at service@webmailer.de to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

In the error log is only

> 23.08.2021 06:03:54 [...] End of script output before headers: cSQL01.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
    
    import sqlite3
    
    def erzeuge_tabellen():
        with sqlite3.connect("strategie.db") as verbindung:
            cursor = verbindung.cursor()
            cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS viren;")
            cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS viren_typ;")
            cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS vorfall;")
            sql = '''CREATE TABLE viren(
                name TEXT PRIMARY KEY,typ INTEGER,status TEXT)'''
            cursor.execute(sql)
            sql = '''CREATE TABLE viren_typ(
                typ INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,groesse INT,signatur TEXT)'''
            cursor.execute(sql)
            sql = '''CREATE TABLE vorfall(
                name TEXT, ort TEXT, vorfall TEXT)'''
            cursor.execute(sql)
    
    def schreibe_daten():
        with sqlite3.connect("strategie.db") as verbindung:
            cursor = verbindung.cursor()
            sql = '''INSERT INTO viren_typ(typ, groesse, signatur)
                VALUES (1, 128, 'ABAABA'),(2, 256, 'ABAABA'),
                (3, 256, 'BCCBCB');'''
            cursor.execute(sql)
            sql = '''INSERT INTO viren(name, typ, status)
                VALUES ('T800', 1, 'aktiv'),('T803', 2, 'aktiv'),
                ('Bit13', 3, 'aktiv'),('Gorf3', 1, 'aktiv'),
                ('Gorf7', 2, 'aktiv');'''
            cursor.execute(sql)
    
    erzeuge_tabellen()
    schreibe_daten()
```

Answer (score 0):

the above script did call the function
ABOVE or WITHOUT that line

print ("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8\n")

having now inserted that line, no error is thrown